# How can i fix this " expected expression before ']' " error message in C?

Tags: c

My Code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
void main()
{
    char s1[]="Avishek",s2[]="Chowdhury";
    puts(s1);
    puts(s2);
    strcat(s1,s2);
    puts(s1);
    s1[]="Avishek",s2[]="Chowdhury";
    strcpy(s1,s2);
    puts(s1);
}
```

When i try to run this code, my codeblocks editor is showing this error message...

**error: expected expression before ']'**

Can anybody suggest me how to fix this...

Comment: The compiler probably gives you a line number, too. What do you see in that line? ;-)

Comment: `s1[]="Avishek",s2[]="Chowdhury";` outside of initialization (sixth line of your `main`) is not legal C. Even if my some manner you manage to address that, this is still a recipe for *undefined behavior*, since `strcat(s1,s2);` will blindly assume the `char` array at `s1` has enough storage for both `"Avishek"` and `"Chowdhury"` (which it does *not*).

Comment: The line `s1[]="Avishek",s2[]="Chowdhury";` is not valid. You can't reassign an array like that.

Comment: Even if you fix the syntax error you program will not work as this `strcat(s1,s2);` leads to UB.

Comment: There’s a big difference between initialization and assignment in C++. Read about them in your favourite C++ book.

Comment: Yes. I got this error for line 10. So, is there any way to reassign an array??

Comment: Once you get the syntax problems sorted out, note that arrays are a bit weird and kind-of second class citizens in C++. I recommend reading the section on arrays in your text carefully. The reasons they are different made perfect sense back in the 1970s when RAM was measured in bytes and only the big boys had Ks of the stuff.

Comment: If you testing different situations then you can redeclare arrays - putting both segments of code in its own block.

Comment: Thanks @Slava and also all of you...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use the `=` operator to assign array contents outside of an initialization.

```
char s1[] = "Avishek";  // this is an initialization, not an assignment - there is a difference
```

declares `s1` as a 8-character array of `char` and copies the contents of the string literal `"Avishek`" to it.  The size of the array is determined by the size of the initializer.  In this case, `"Avishek"` requires 8 characters (7 for the printing characters, 1 for the string terminator).

The line

```
s1[] = "Avishek"; // this is an assignment
```

is failing because you cannot use an empty `[]` operator on an array outside of a declaration - the compiler thinks you're trying to access a specific element of the array, but you're missing the index value between the `[` and `]` operators (hence the "expected expression before ']'" error message).

However,

```
s1 = "Avishek";
```

won't work either - you cannot assign array expressions using the `=` operator.  To reset `s1` to contain the string `"Avishek"`, you must use the `strcpy` library function instead:

```
strcpy( s1, "Avishek" );
```

So your code would read

```
strcat(s1,s2);
puts(s1);
strcpy(s1, "Avishek");
strcpy(s2, "Chowdhury");
strcpy(s1,s2);
```

Except you have a couple of other problems.  Arrays in C don't grow or shrink automatically.  If you want to concatenate `s2` to `s1` in the line

```
strcat(s1,s2);
```

then `s1` needs to be declared large enough to store the resulting string, and in this case it isn't.  You've only declared `s1` to be large enough to store `"Avishek"`.  To avoid a buffer overflow, you'll have to specify the size of `s1` in the declaration:

```
char s1[18] = "Avishek"; // large enough to store "AvishekChowdhury"
char s2[] = "Chowdhury";
```

One final change is that `main` returns `int`, not `void`.  So your changes need to be

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char s1[18]="Avishek";
    char s2[]="Chowdhury";

    puts(s1);
    puts(s2);
    strcat(s1,s2);
    puts(s1);
    strcpy(s1, "Avishek");
    strcpy(s2, "Chowdhury");
    strcpy(s1,s2);
    puts(s1);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: This answer is so good, I'm now tempted to upvote the question ;-).

Answer (score 0):

If you try to test different situations then this solution will make your code compile:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{
    {
        char s1[]="Avishek",s2[]="Chowdhury";
        puts(s1);
        puts(s2);
        strcat(s1,s2);
        puts(s1);
    }
    {
        char s1[]="Avishek",s2[]="Chowdhury";
        strcpy(s1,s2);
        puts(s1);
    }
}
```

note you do not reassign arrays but recreate them and `s1`,`s2` in first block are different than `s1`, `s2` in the second. But this will not make your program correct as you have Undefined Behavior in this line:

```
        strcat(s1,s2);
```

this can be solved to make array `s1` big enough:

```
        char s1[32]="Avishek",s2[]="Chowdhury"; // make s1 big enough to concatenate later
```

Comment: This “answer” does not explain what is wrong with `s1[]="Avishek",s2[]="Chowdhury";`. Just giving people working code without explaining what was wrong with the old code or why is not a good answer. It does not teach people the concepts they need to know.

Comment: @EricPostpischil bro, I got the concept from previous comments. Not a problem...

Comment: @AvishekChowdhury: Stack Overflow is not a personal service for individuals. It is intended to be a durable repository of questions and answers for anybody to use. If an “answer” does not contain the answer, it is not useful for people who find this question in the future. Comments are ephemeral; they can be deleted at any time, so answers in them are inadequate for this purpose.

Comment: @EricPostpischil In all reality though, there is not much to say about that line except that it's ungrammatical.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica: That may be trivial information to you, but it is not to people learning the language. The fact that somebody has made such a mistake is evidence they did not have the information, and therefore that it should be supplied.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Dare I say that the compiler error *is* that information? But I must admit that John's excellent answer demonstrates that it is possible to guess the OP's intent and explain why it does not work and what to do instead.